# Create a Promise which is not resolved yet in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking to create a Promise which is not resolved yet. 
I'd create this promise and have some processes waiting on it to be resolved. It would only get resolved when I actually assign another promise of a call I am making. But at first, all my processes would wait on this Promise forever until I reassign it. How can I do this with a ES6 Promise.

I know I can create an already resolved Promise with :

```
Promise.resolve('')
```

So that would kind of be the opposite.

Comment: [`new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create that kind of promise like this:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('some value');
    // or
    reject('some value');
});
```

The `resolve` and `reject` parameters to the function are themselves functions that can be used to resolve or reject the promise, respectively. They both accept a value which will be the promise's resolved value.

Check out [MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   // If you want to resolve:
   resolve(optionalParam);

   // If you want to reject:
   reject(optionalParam);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create references to `resolve`, `reject` of `Promise` constructor

```js
// assign `resolve`, `reject` functions of `promise` within `Promise` constructor
let _resolve = _reject = void 0;

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  _resolve = resolve; // define `resolve` as `_resolve` to outer scope
  _reject = reject; // define `reject` as `_reject` at outer scope
});

promise
// do stuff when `promise` resolves or rejects
.then(function handleFulfilled(data) {
  console.log(data)
}, function handleErr(err) {
     console.log(err)
});

function fn(t, res, err, value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve()
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * t))
  })
  .then(function() {
     return res(value)
  })
}

fn(3000, _resolve, null, "abc")
// do stuff after `promise` resolved or rejected
.then(function() {
  console.log("promise resolved")
}, function(err) {
     console.log("promise rejected", err)
});
```